# How to import multiple image into Excel by Java POI

Tags: java, image, apache-poi

Is there any way to import multi picture and text into a cell of excel?
I'm using Java POI.
This is
[my expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDRej.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Pictures are not **in** cells in Excel. They hover in a drawing layer over the cells and only are anchored on the cells. So you need calculating the anchor position. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57822868/apache-poi-insert-2-images-in-one-cell-with-differend-anchor-properites/57823512#57823512 for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pictures are not **in** cells in Excel. They hover in a drawing layer over the cells and only are anchored on the cells. So you need calculating the anchor position. That requires following knowledge:

A [ClientAnchor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/ClientAnchor.html) has following properties:

Col1 = top left edge of the shape is ancored on left edge of that column

Row1 =  top left edge of the shape is ancored on top edge of that row

Col2 = bottom right edge of the shape is ancored on left edge of that column

Row2 = bottom right edge of the shape is ancored on top edge of that row

Dx1 = delta x to shift top left edge of the shape away from the left edge of the Col1

Dy1 = delta y to shift top left edge of the shape away from the top edge of the Row1

Dx2 = delta x to shift bottom right edge of the shape away from the left edge of the Col2

Dy2 = delta y to shift bottom right edge of the shape away from the top edge of the Row2

Note, measurement unit for dx and dy is EMU (English Metric Unit). There is [Units](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/util/Units.html) to handle those strange measurement units properly.

Additional we need some math.

Take the method `void addImage` from example of [Apache Poi, insert 2 images in one cell with differend anchor properites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57822868/apache-poi-insert-2-images-in-one-cell-with-differend-anchor-properites/57823512#57823512) and use it like so:

```
...
 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

  workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
  sheet = workbook.createSheet();

  int gapTopPx = 10;
  int gapLeftPx = 20;
  int gapBetweenPx = 30;
  int gapBelowPx = 40;
  
  sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 30*256);
  int columnWidthPx = Math.round(sheet.getColumnWidthInPixels(0));
  sheet.createRow(0).setHeightInPoints((float)Units.pixelToPoints(gapTopPx+pictureHeightPx*2+gapBetweenPx+gapBelowPx));
  
  sheet.getRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue("Two pictures in A1");
  
  addImage(0, 0, 0, 0, /*all fits in cell A1*/
   /*Dx1 = gap left and Dy1 = gap top*/
   Units.pixelToEMU(gapLeftPx), Units.pixelToEMU(gapTopPx), 
   /*Dx2 is gap left plus picture's width and Dy2 is gap top plus first picture's height*/
   Units.pixelToEMU(gapLeftPx + pictureWidthPx), Units.pixelToEMU(gapTopPx + pictureHeightPx),
   pictureFileNames[0], pictureTypes[0], ClientAnchor.AnchorType.MOVE_AND_RESIZE);

  addImage(0, 0, 0, 0, /*all fits in cell A1*/
   /*Dx1 = gap left and Dy1 = gap top plus first picture's height plus gap between pictures*/
   Units.pixelToEMU(gapLeftPx), Units.pixelToEMU(gapTopPx + pictureHeightPx + gapBetweenPx), 
   /*Dx2 is gapleft plus picture's width and Dy2 is gap top plus first picture's height plus gab betweeen pictures plus second picture's height*/
   Units.pixelToEMU(gapLeftPx + pictureWidthPx), Units.pixelToEMU(gapTopPx + pictureHeightPx + gapBetweenPx + pictureHeightPx),
   pictureFileNames[1], pictureTypes[1], ClientAnchor.AnchorType.MOVE_AND_RESIZE);
   

  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(excelPath);
  workbook.write(fos);
  fos.close();
  workbook.close();

 }
...
```

This results in:

[image]